# How to do a filter in mongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where I am storing like below

```
 "role" : [ 
                {
                    "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee00d",
                    "earn" : {
                        "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E2",
                        "5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0",
                        "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2",
                        "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5",
                        "5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0",
                        "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E4"
                    }
                 }
           ]
```

I need to fetch only the earn value Which doesn't have "E0".

```
 "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E2",
 "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2",
 "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5",
 "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E4"
```

Comment: Is role the name of the collection or a key in one of the documents?

Comment: no it's not the name of collection. Its a key field

Comment: can you provide more details of what you need : result as array elements or object fields? role_id?

Comment: How have you found it possible to have the field name of `5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1` to be repeated twice in one document with a different value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an aggregation query as follows

```
db.roles.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$role" },
  {$project : { earn : { $objectToArray: "$role.earn" }}},
  {$unwind : "$earn" },
  {$match: { "earn.v" : { $ne : "E0" }}},
]);
```

When executed on the following collection

```
> db.roles.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d4db5217b959d85f79899"),
        "role" : [
                {
                        "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee00d",
                        "earn" : {
                                "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5",
                                "5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0",
                                "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E4"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

You'll get the following output

```
> db.roles.aggregate([
...   {$unwind: "$role" },
...   {$project : { earn : { $objectToArray: "$role.earn" }}},
...   {$unwind : "$earn" },
...   {$match: { "earn.v" : { $ne : "E0" }}},
... ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d4db5217b959d85f79899"), "earn" : { "k" : "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0", "v" : "E5" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d4db5217b959d85f79899"), "earn" : { "k" : "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce", "v" : "E4" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this schema :

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d29d239bd595000edf3ee"), 
    "role" : [
        {
            "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee00d", 
            "earn" : {
                "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
                "5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0", 
                "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
                "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
                "5943c46ec74b036a883efab1" : "E0", 
                "594a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee02d", 
            "earn" : {
                "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
                "6943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0", 
                "694a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
                "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
                "6943c46ec74b036a883efab1" : "E0", 
                "694a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Try this below aggregation

```
   { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8d29d239bd595000edf3ee"), 
    "role" : [
        {
            "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee00d", 
            "earn" : {
                "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
                "5943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0", 
                "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
                "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
                "5943c46ec74b036a883efab1" : "E0", 
                "594a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "role_id" : "599adabbef17f85afbcee02d", 
            "earn" : {
                "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
                "6943c46ec74b036a883efaf1" : "E0", 
                "694a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
                "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
                "6943c46ec74b036a883efab1" : "E0", 
                "694a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

will return :

```
{ 
    "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
    "594a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
    "5943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
    "594a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4", 
    "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf5" : "E2", 
    "694a0b08c74b030a2ae33cce" : "E2", 
    "6943c3f7c74b036a883efaf0" : "E5", 
    "694a0b08c74b030a2ae34cce" : "E4"
}
```

Hope it helps...